# php + oci8, table type column, ORA-00932

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

My context: i'm developing and supporting some php application, working with Billing APP API trough Oracle functions/procedures and views.
From time to time i'm updating my code because of billing API changes.
But last update billing api update has broke all =\

API developers has added to allmost all views table-type column. Here is it's definition:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "AIS_NET"."SI_V_SUBJECTS" ... AS 
  SELECT N_SUBJECT_ID,
.....
CAST(
         MULTISET(
           SELECT VC_CODE
           FROM   SI_V_ENTITIES_TAGS
           WHERE  N_ENTITY_ID = S.N_SUBJECT_ID
           AND    N_ENTITY_TYPE_ID = SYS_CONTEXT('CONST', 'ENTITY_TYPE_Subject')
           ORDER BY N_LINE_NO) AS TAGS)                T_TAGS,
.....
```

And when i'm trying to fetch

```
select * from SI_V_SUBJECTS
```

i'm getting an error:

```
oci_fetch_assoc(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got TABLE
```

If i define columns without T_TAGS, something like "select N_SUBJECT_ID, VC_CODE FROM SI_V_SUBJECTS", all is good.

But i dont want to go through all of my code and define fields to selecting.

Maybe there is some hints/tricks to fetch table type columns with php/oci8?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I'm not aware of hijacking techniques in PHP, but you may want to google that. In JavaScript you may do smth like `obj.old_someMethod = obj.someMethod; obj.someMethod = function(...) { /*use this.old_someMethod here*/ };` to modify some function globaly. I'm afraid this is not called "hijacking" in PHP, though.

Comment: I have not found any solution, but i've make some workaround:

i'm using Laravel, and i have added array $columns[] to all models, excluding T_TAGS column.
Cloned Eloquent\Builder to my own EloquentBuilder and replaced function get($columns = ['*']), checking arguments and replacing columns with model's columns, if they are empty.